# WooCommerce plugin appearance and look

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to customize WooCommerce plugin the same as my own theme?

Im about to finish the theme development, and I was wondering if it's possible to style the WooCommerce Checkout system that it looks the same as the theme Im creating?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible - take a look at the woocommerce documentation:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/css-structure/
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

You can find the information you need there.