# How To Customize Position of »add to cart« of WooCommerce on Product Page

Tags: php, customization, plugins

Which file (or files, if more than one) do I need to edit to re-arrange the Product Page?

I want to make some basic layout changes to the default Woocommerce product page. Specifically, I want to put the Order stuff just below the Price, and push the description down.  In other words, swap the Short Description with the Order Stuff (Attributes, Add to Cart, SKU, etc.)  Here is a screenshot of what I want to do: http://d.pr/i/YGAY

Comment: Take look at my answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113189/22534. Btw those are many questions, the concept of this site is to ask questions concerning one solvable problem.

Comment: Thank you @ialocin. I have already seen those "structure" pages and spent quite a bit of time hacking around various files to no avail. Sorry if you mis-interpreted my question, but it was intended to be singular (and specific):

Which file (or files, if more than one) do I need to edit to  re-arrange the Product Page as shown in my screenshot?

I just want to move the Buy Now button and Attributes Selector up above the Product Description.

Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to help. See, what you wrote in your comment is a problem I - somebody - can work with. I post an answer for you, how to solve this. Can you please rewrite your question to reflect this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do what you want by hooking into the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action. The action is executed inside `content-single-product.php` like this:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

Above you have a description/documentation about the hooked in parts, the number represents the priority and/or order.

You can change the priority/order by removing and re-adding the parts you want the postion changed - like this:

```
    /** woocommerce: change position of add-to-cart on single product **/
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
               'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
            'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 9 );
```

Drop this piece of code into your `functions.php` to take effect. The add-to-cart part now should show after title and before price, if you want it to show after the price - for example - choose a number - in above code, on the `add_action()` line - between 11 to 19 - I'm sure you are getting the principle by now.

Comment: It's been some time on this, but I thank you for your help. That worked!  Once I figured out the method, I made some more edits. I have also changed my original question to better match my problem.  Thank you again @ialocin

Comment: @BlakeMiller Any time, glad you figured it out and now are able to use it further! If it's a correct answer give it a check mark, so everybody coming to the question later knows that.

Comment: How can I position it above the Add to Cart button but below variations?

Comment: @MF1 I'm not sure, you've to inspect it yourself. Good luck!